# How to handle multiple error pages for different exceptions in Spring

Tags: java, spring, exception, custom-error-pages

I think I saw it somewhere before but I cannot find it.
My problem is to set different error pages, one for my detailed exception eg. pl.app.MyException and another for every other exception.
My web.xml looks like:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/exception.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>pl.app.MyException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/myException.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

but every exception redirects to exception.jsp. Is it possible to do this and how? Any help appreciated

Comment: did you define an ExceptionResolver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that error-page is a configuration parameter related to the servlet container, not Spring. You should use an [Exception resolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers).
See [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exception-handling-example/) for a good tutorial.

Comment: Yes, I just found the same page, bean org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver implementation just works fine